# execute immediate error when performing create directory command in pl sql

Tags: plsql

```
execute immediate 'CREATE or replace DIRECTORY user_dir AS' ||'"C:\proc"';
```

When execute the code above, it is throwing following error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-01780: string literal required
>
> ORA-06512: at "databasename.WRITEDATA", line 7
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
declare

a varchar2(100);

begin

a:= q'[CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY g_vid_lib AS '/video/library/g_rated']';
execute immediate a;

end;
```

This will create directory on the server where oracle is installed not on your machine drive.

```
SQL> select * from dba_directories where lower(directory_name) = 'g_vid_lib';

OWNER                DIRECTORY_NAME          DIRECTORY_PATH
------------------------------ ------------------------------      
SYS                  G_VID_LIB              /video/library/g_rated
```

In your case it goes like:

```
declare

a varchar2(100);

begin

a:= q'[CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY g_vid_lib AS 'C:\procedure']';
execute immediate a;

end;
```

Comment: If you assign here you will get error "string literal required"..but you can use your path as well.. Check my updated statement,

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY user_dir AS ''C:\proc''';
END;
```

should do the trick. The "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" needs to be within an begin/end block and pay attention to the single quotation marks needed as escape characters.